# catch mysql errors before sending HTTP response

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I am coming from php background where sql queries are blocking.

My usual setup is to make a `try, catch` block to handle any possible errors that might happen during table updating. I wanted to transfer this logic to nodejs, but it's asynchronous nature is making this troublesome. Take a look at example code:

```
var httpServer = Https.createServer(httpsOptions, function (request, response) {


try {
     //many queries in if-else, switch statements
     if(something){
     mysqlConnection.query(query,[],function(err, result){});
     }else{
     //many queries will follow
       if(somethingelse){
        mysqlConnection.query(query2,[],function(err, result){});
       }else{
        mysqlConnection.query(query3,[],function(err, result){});
          if(andsoon){}
       }
     }

     response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
     response.end("Got it.");
     console.log("Response successful");
}catch(error){
     console.error(error);
     response.writeHead(400, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
     response.end("Error.");
}

}).listen(8000);
```

So, `response.end()` will trigger before the query executes so I send the message before I know if the query was successful. I could wrap the `response.end()` code in callback, but there are MANY queries that are executing, so now I have to track how many were executed so far. Things get worse, 1 if-else control flow requires just 1 query, some other requires 10 so there is crazy overhead with tracking when the code is completed.

This all can't be the optimal workflow. What do you do when you have a complex query  system and you want to send response only after all queries have executed(or failed)?

Answer (score 0):

You've put null callbacks from your .query invocations. That's your problem.

```
mysqlConnection.query(query,[],function(err, result){});
                               xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Javascript goes on to run the next statement after the one shown *immediately without waiting for the query to finish*. You know the query is complete (or it hit an error) only when the .query method invokes your callback function.

So, you need to do something like this instead.

```
mysqlConnection.query(query,[],function(err, result){
    if (err) throw Error(err);
    //many queries will follow
    if(somethingelse){
           ...
    }
});
```

A sequence of queries like you need ends up with an absurdly deeply nested set of callback functions. But don't despair: Javascript's Promise pattern works around this for you and gives you clean code. Use [npm's promise-mysql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql). And write code like this.

```
    mysqlConnection.query(query,[])
    .then (function(mySqlConnection) {
         if (somethingelse) 
             return mysqlConnection.query(query2,[]) 
         else
             return mysqlConnection.query(query3,[]) 
         })
     .then (function(mySqlConnection) {
          return mysqlConnection.query(query4,[]) 
         })
     .then (function(mySqlConnection) {
          response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
          response.end("Got it.");
         })
     .catch (function(err)) {
          /* failure somewhere ! */
         });
```

You have a series of then functions, with a catch at the end. The Promise subsystem hides all the callback invocation for you, organizing it this way instead.  (Notice that I did not debug this sample code.)

You must figure out this [Promise stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to program sql / nodejs successfully.  It's counterintuitive at first (at least it was for me when I was learning it). But it's worth your effort.  Pro tip: if you're stepping through this kind of code in a debugger,  use Step Into liberally.